# Importing a module from subdirectory causes it to not find other modules in its directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following structure

```
> external.py
- folder1
   - folder2
      > a.py
      > b.py
```

File a.py:

```
from b import functionB
```

File external.py:

```
from folder1.folder2.a import functionA
```

If I now call `python a.py` everything works. But calling `python external.py` results in:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'`

If I change the import in file `a.py` to:

```
from .b import functionB
```

then calling `python external.py` works, but `python a.py` results in:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Why is module b suddenly not visible anymore when I import module a from outside the folder structure?

I tried adding `__init__.py` files at several places without much success.

Comment: add the init in each directory / folder... and then tell us what the result is

Comment: adding __init__.py to the folders does not change the error messages for imports without dots. When switching to relative imports I get No module named '__main__.b'; '__main__' is not a package
The solution to that according to SO is to remove the dot.

Answer (score 0):

Add a try except statement in `a.py` and that should work fine, this happens as working directory changes when you import the `a.py` from `external.py`

```
try:
    from b import functionB
except ImportError:
    from folder1.folder2.b import functionb
```

Comment: This is a very ugly hack. Is there no better / best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: There is another way you can simply import the os library and change the working directory manually, but you may still have to use a try except method, if there another way beyond this, sorry I may not be able to help

Comment: Thanks for your help Avijeet. I was just hoping that there was a best practice way of using bundled scripts from any location. But I guess that would be putting them in a package and installing that package through pip